# jquery slideout button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Below source for jquery slideout

```
jQuery(function($) 
{
        $('#slideClick').toggle(function() {
            $(this).parent().animate({left:'0px'}, {queue:false, duration: 500});
        }, function() {
            $(this).parent().animate({left:'-290px'}, {queue:false, duration: 500});
        }); 
    });
```

I'm trying to do, after `submit` the button, I try to show send successfully and back to empty text box window.

how to fix enquiry form fix same position, not going to up and down when I scroll the page. thanks

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bala2024/Zv79N/

Comment: Why don't you just put the fiddle link in your question body since you have the code here?

Comment: What does "jQuery(function($)" do?  Is it supposed to be the document.ready() call?

Comment: cant find the submit button in fiddle.

Comment: hi plz could you check the following link: http://jsfiddle.net/bala2024/Zv79N/27/

Answer (score 0):

this question should be marked as CSS question not javascript. 
anyway this is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zv79N/24/)

a little fixed was needed, except of adding positioning to the `id="slideClick"` you should add `fixed` positioning to the parent, so the parent (`id="slideOut"`) will be fixed (so the `id="slideClick"` will be fixed')

`#slideOut {
    position:fixed;
    width:310px;
    height:80px;
    top:45%;
    left:-290px;
}`

was all you need

Comment: Even if the solution involves CSS, the question itself isn't inherently about CSS.